# Converting exponential number to decimal 1.11111117E+9 - trailing digits become zero

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal, tryparse, exponential

I'm trying to convert and exponential number 1.11111117E+9 which is actually a 10 digit number '1111111111'. When I'm trying to convert this exponential number using decimal.TryParse method it is making last 3 digits as zero and giving the number as '**111111000**'. This is happening with any 10 digit number.

```
   decimal amount;
   decimal.TryParse("1.11111117E+9", NumberStyles.Any, null, out amount);
```

This is weird but I'm not able to figure out what's the issue here, can anybody tell me what's wrong in this?

**Edit:**
Sorry for the misleading question. As **Henrik** mentioned in his answer is exactly what I'm facing.

```
float f = 1111111111;
string s = f.ToString();
decimal amount;
decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, null, out amount);
```

This will always return 1111111000? How do I address this issue to get the correct value? Change it to Double or Decimal from float datatype is the solution or anything else?

Comment: [Have a look here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/csharpgeneral/thread/63703ff5-5f67-4c49-b20d-4177855b58ab)

Comment: '111111111' is a *9* digit number, and is certainly not equal to '1.11111117E+9'. Your question is far from clear...

Comment: Also worth noting is that 1.11111117E9 will be 1111111170. if you have insufficient precision in your source number you will need to have some zeros at the end to pad it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry for the mistyping. Corrected it.

Comment: @Chris: Actually that number is coming from a sqlite db and it is stored in that way in the DB as well. While storing it is stored from a float variable and AddParameter() is used to store that value.

Comment: @JPReddy: Wherever it's coming from, 1.11111117E+9 is *not* 1111111111.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You are correct. Verified the value now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to round-trip a float value...

```
float f = 1111111111;
string s = f.ToString("r"); // r = roundtrip
float g = float.Parse(s);
```

Now `f` and `g` will be the same... but that doesn't mean that either value is exactly 1111111111... because that value *can't be represented as a float*. The nearest value exactly representable as a float is 1111111168... which is why you're getting the 7 at the end of the scientific representation.

Basically, you shouldn't be using `float` for this in the first place. From the docs for [System.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx):

> By default, a Single value contains only 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

So trying to store a 10 digit number and expecting it to be stored exactly is a fool's errand.

It's hard to say whether you should be using `double` or `decimal` - it depends on what value you're really trying to store. If it's a "natural" value like weight or height, I'd go for `double`. If it's a "human" value like a price, I'd use `decimal`.

Comment: I think I made a mistake by storing the 10 digit value in float, that is the reason all this mess up. It is a financial value so I will go with decimal though I need to compromise on performance.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
decimal amount;
decimal.TryParse("1.11111117E+9", NumberStyles.Any, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out amount);
```

sets amount to 1111111170M, as expected.

Note the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, so it does not depend on your local settings.

Update: I suspect your real code looks something like this:

```
float f = 1111111111;
string s = f.ToString();
decimal amount;
decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, null, out amount);
```

f is displayed in the debuger as 1.11111117e+9, s is 1.111111e+9 and amount 1111111000M.
The reason for all this is the limited precision of float.

Comment: You got the right point in my question, even though my question is quite confusing and incorrect. Your float explanation applies to my question. Yes that is what the problem I'm facing. Can you explain more about limited precision of float. How do I address this issue in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
It works better for me

```
 decimal dec = Decimal.Parse("1.11111117E+9", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse `double`, not `decimal`. Scientific notation has no place with `decimal`.

Update: The exact integer value is `1111111170`. Not `111111111` which is about 10 times less than what it should be.

Comment: I'd argue that scientific notation actually makes more sense with decimal than with double, in terms of the mantissa/exponent form being in the same base in the string as in the native format for decimal.

Comment: Parsing double or decimal doesn't return the correct value. Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @JPReddy: Your code doesn't have the correct value to start with, because it can't be represented in a float. Garbage in, garbage out...