# Best way to handle long integers in a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, long-integer

I have a csv file with a column where the integers are over 16 characters long. The issue with this is that it changes the integer to a short abbreviation example: 8.71688E+17, is there a way in c# you can convert it back to a long integer without having to modify the csv file itself?

I currently convert the CSV file to a datatable, could there be a way at the conversion stage?

Comment: These may help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723537/converting-exponential-number-to-decimal-1-11111117e9-trailing-digits-become

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BitInteger` class. Here's more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class

Answer (score 0):

prefix value with '=' and enclose large-value inside double quote so final string to put into excel cell is  `="<large-value>"`